# pushViewController(UIViewController(), animated: true) does't work inside custom collection view cell button target function

Tags: swift

i want to navigate the new view controller within button target function witch inside custom collection view cell

```
   import UIKit
    class ItemDetailsHeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let likeImage : UIButton = {

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "like").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: [])
    btn.tintColor = main_color
    return btn
}()

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(likeImage)
   // anchor function to put constrains

    likeImage.anchor(bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: 
    bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, 
     bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, 
     heightConstant: 50)
     likeImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeWeb), for: 
    .touchDown)
   }

   @objc func likeWeb() {

      // here it is not work 
       let controller =  ItemDetailsViewController(collectionViewLayout: 
       UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

        controller.itemid = String( indexPath.row )

        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: 
        true)
    }

}
```

note: iam only using swift code ,  there is no any storeboard in my project

Answer (score 1):

```
@objc func likeWeb() {

      // here it is not work 
       let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemDetailsViewControllerIdentifier") as! ItemDetailsViewController

        controller.itemid = String( indexPath.row )

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: 
        true)
    }
```

Comment: it is not work , and i mention that iam not using storeboard in my project

Answer (score 0):

[this post may help you](https://makeapppie.com/2016/07/11/programmatic-navigation-view-controllers-in-swift-3-0/)

```
 let vc = TwoViewController(nibName: "TwoViewController",bundle: nil)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

change to "lazy var" instead of "let"

```
    lazy var likeImage : UIButton = {

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "like").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: [])
    btn.tintColor = main_color
    return btn
}()
```